# Swift 3 Passing ArrayList object variables to String Array

Tags: ios, swift, arraylist, swift3, xcode8

I have a list of objects that have a getName func that returns a string, and am looking to populate another list of Strings by looping through the first list and calling the objects functions to pass it through. Right now my code looks like this.

```
    let brT = Skill(name: "brT", difficulty: 0.6)
    let brP = Skill(name: "brP", difficulty: 0.7)
    let brS = Skill(name: "brS", difficulty: 0.7)
    let bkT = Skill(name: "bkT", difficulty: 0.6)
    let bkP = Skill(name: "bkP", difficulty: 0.6)
    let bkS = Skill(name: "bkS", difficulty: 0.6)

    let list1 = [brT, brP, brS, bkT, brP, brS]

    var list: <String>

    for (index, element) in list1.enumerated() {
        list.append(element.getName())
    }
```

I'm trying to do this for an app so the list of Strings display in a table view, and then the double will sum all the doubles and display to a UI label below the table. Finally I need the String list to be able to be looked through for a search bar that can add the object string variable to the table view, and add the double to another list that does the label output I mentioned above, am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

You should declare and initialize list like this:

```
var list = [String]()
```

which is the same as:

```
var list = Array<String>()
```

Also, there's no need for `enumerated()` here. Just do:

```
for element in list1 {
    list.append(element.getName())
}
```

Or, better yet, use `map` to do everything in a single step, making `list` a constant:

```
let list = list1.map { $0.getName() }
```